# Simple annotation processor library project with Maven

Tags: java, maven, annotations, annotation-processing

I am trying to create a simple library that defines annotations and annotation processors with Maven using Netbeans 12.3. This library will be used by a web project that uses the annotations.

The problem is that the processor classes are not found when compiling the library, although they are in the source: "Annotation processor 'bandung.processor.CommandProcessor' not found"

(The annotations worked fine in a non-Maven project under a previous version of Netbeans.)

Here is the POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.ipserlab</groupId>
    <artifactId>Bandung</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-email</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
            <artifactId>lucene-analyzers-common</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.htmlparser</groupId>
            <artifactId>HTMLParserProject</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.htmlparser</groupId>
            <artifactId>htmlparser</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.auto.service</groupId>
            <artifactId>auto-service</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <generatedSourcesDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/</generatedSourcesDirectory>
                    <annotationProcessors>
                        <annotationProcessor>
                            bandung.processor.CommandProcessor
                        </annotationProcessor>
                        <annotationProcessor>
                            bandung.processor.ModelProcessor
                        </annotationProcessor>
                    </annotationProcessors>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

I just needed to add

```
<proc>none</proc>
```

to the configuration. Thanks to Malav Doshi.

Comment: Please also accept this answer since it obviously solved your problem. Accepted answers are more helpful for the community.